# Forced teleportation of traps?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

Recently I was DM and the wizard decided to use "hammerfall step" to teleport a trap into a pit where it couldn't do anything. The trap was fixed to the floor so it could not be pushed, but could it be teleported?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work. That said, great first question, +1!

Answer (score 12):

I think that depends on the definition of what you consider a legal target for Hammerfall Step.

The power specifically states each *enemy* in blast. **Source: Arcane Power pg. 116**

Since I don't rule traps as enemies, I wouldn't allow him to teleport the trap at all. If it can't be picked up, it wouldn't be able to be teleported. Additionally, this would open the system up to massive abuse. If he can teleport a trap, then what's to stop him from teleporting the key to a blacksmith's shop? Or the spellbook he likes off a shelf? I mean the possibilities for abuse are endless if you permit him to use that power to move an object.

Comment: Upvoted. Because the spell specifically targets enemies, I don't think it can be applied to an inert object like a trap.